# Javascript Window.ScrollTop() Chrome Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Im implementing an infinite scrolldown loading on my web app but somehow cannot make it work in Google Chrome, my code does work on my IE11 and Edge. Before, it was working on my google chrome but today cannot make it work and I cannot seem to trace back the changes that affected it. (or maybe my chrome settings but I already reset it back to defaults)
Here's my code:

```
var scrollHandler = function () {
            if (hasReachedEndOfInfiniteScroll == false && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())) {
                alert(1);
                loadMoreToInfiniteScrollTable(moreRowsUrl);
            }
        }
```

Im having problem at the `($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())`
as it never returns true when using Google Chrome.

Anyone can help me trace the issue? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this. Try to come near bottom and then fire ajax call.

```
var ScrollBottom = 100;

if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > 
    $(document).height() - ScrollBottom) { 
    loadMoreToInfiniteScrollTable(moreRowsUrl);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but what im trying to do is when the user reaches the bottom of the page through scrolling down, this function will be called: `loadMoreToInfiniteScrollTable(moreRowsUrl);`

Comment: @super-user try the edited one.  Is that what you want

Comment: Oh wow, it works now, idk why it doesn't work without that (-100) in the formula. Thanks alot man!!

Comment: @super-user glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you use the document object, it will work, try this

```
                           $(document).scrollTop();
```